# How do I set a new State to test an observable?

Tags: jasmine, ngrx

I have tried all the day to make a simple test in jasmine, but i think i am doing something wrong. I have a piece of code that i wish to test, but i can't go inside. I was trying to follow nrgx 7 documentation, but i failed.

The unit test below should test my enderecoFeatureSubscription. The store.setState({ cep: null, endereco: RES }) is doing nothing with the store, so my subscription doens't do anything

```
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
  let store: MockStore<ICepState>
  const initialState = {
    cep: null, endereco: null
  };
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FormComponent],
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}),],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState: CEPSTATE })
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });
  it('should test enderecoFeatureSubscription ', () => {
    store.setState({ cep: null, endereco: RES })
    expect(component.endereco).toEqual(RES)
  });
```

Component

```
private enderecoFeatureSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(enderecoFeatureSelector)).subscribe((endereco: IEndereco | any) => {
    if (!endereco) {
      return;
    }
    this.endereco = endereco
  })
```

If you can help i thank you, because i hav wasted a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some changes to my test work fine.
1 - Removed 'const initialState' and imported from my app state file.
2 - The type of MockStore, i changed to my app state type
3 - In the test, i set a new value to 'cepState.endereco' and call setState with initialState
4 - I changed 'store' for 'mockStore', but it doesn't make diference
5 - finally, i brought the right import

Look the code bellow:

```
describe('FormComponent', () => {
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
  let mockStore: MockStore<AppState>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FormComponent],
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({ 'cepState': CepReducer })
      ],
      providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState })]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);
  });

  it('should test new endereco state', () => {
    initialState.cepState.endereco = RES
    mockStore.setState(initialState)
    expect(component.endereco).toEqual(RES)
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ngrx ver. > 8.0.0, there is a method `store.refreshState` refreshes the state if you use `store.setState` on respective overridden selectors. Unfortunately, `refreshState` method does not exist in ngrx 7. There is an alternative to that - you should override the desired selector using `store.overrideSelector` like this -

```
it('should test enderecoFeatureSubscription ', () => {
    store.overrideSelector(enderecoFeatureSelector, <put you mocked value>
    fixture.detectChanges(); //MAKE sure to remove fixture.detectChanges() from beforeEach
    expect(component.endereco).toEqual(RES)
  });
```

Comment: Did you remove fixture.detectChanges from beforeEach?